# Server not starting, after adding graphisc card

Tags: hardware, gpu

First of all, I want to clarify, that I pretty new to server topics.
My server runs on normal ubuntu.

I bought a Nvidia Quadro k4000.

1. I built it into the server and connected the PCIe Power cable. - System health LED red
2. I plugged out the PCIe power cable - Starts up, and the screen tells me to power down and plug in the cable
3. I plug in the cable. -Return to step 1

What I tried:

1. Check if it is plugged in correctly
2. Try another cable
3. run the system again without the card. - works on its own

Please help me.

Comment: Your PSU probably doesn't supply enough power. Check their specifications.

Comment: It is specified for 460 Watts. The GPu uses 80 W. I measured 120 W. on startup, before I tried to intall it.

Comment: Also, do two PSUs double the watts it can deliver, or just for redundancy?